# input form-control doesn't accept 0 in android

Tags: android, html, css

I have a form with date and cpf (brazilian id). It all work perfect in a PC and an iphone, but not in a mobile with android.

The fields date and cpf uses a mask "00/00/00" for date and "000.000.000-00" for cpf. The problem is it doesn't accept the user to input the number 0. It means I can for example enter the date "11/11/1998", but not "10/11/1998", because of the "0". I click in 0, but it's like I am clicking a letter and nothing happens and this problem only occurs in android.

Any idea what could be? Here is the form:

```
<div class=" row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="user_dashboard_panel">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>
                    <label for="dateofbirth"><?php esc_html_e('Date','wpestate');?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="dateofbirth" class="form-control date" value="<?php echo $date_ofbirth;?>"  name="dateofbirth">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="cpf"><?php esc_html_e('CPF','wpestate');?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="cpf" class="form-control formatCPF" value="<?php echo $cpf;?>"  name="cpf">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Excuse me sir, it seems something with `esc_html_e`. Could you show it for us? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @statosdotcom I doubt it,. since that's only the content of the label, which doesn't influence the input.

Comment: @MrLister thank you. I thought **esc_html_e** was the validation routine script responsible to the masking mentioned by OP. Thought it was there the possible matter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for the support. Sorry Mr. Lister I couldn't provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, but I will consider that next time.

I am not completely sure about the issue, but it was probably mobile/os/browser version, which just on android was not working.

Anyways, my solution was to change the placeholder. I had a placeholder for the date like "00/00/0000", so I wasn't able to type 0 in a real date. Therefor I just replaced the placeholder to "--/--/----". Now it works!

Thanks!